# Bug with two carets input for multibyte characters (`^^xx^^xx`) in LuaTeX or XeTeX?

Tags: xetex, luatex, bugs

When inputting characters using their hexadecimal codes, LuaTeX and XeTeX do not allow to use two caret notation ^^xx for multibyte characters. While `^^^^041f` works fine (shows cyrillic 'Т'), `^^d0^^9f` (which is the same 'Т' in UTF-8) shows two glyphs. MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{CMU Serif}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\begin{document}
A word in Russian: ^^d0^^9f^^d1^^80^^d0^^b8^^d0^^b2^^d0^^b5^^d1^^82^^21

Four carets work fine: ^^^^041f^^^^0440^^^^0438^^^^0432^^^^0435^^^^0442^^^^0021
\end{document}
```

[image]

For the PdFTeX engine the `^^xx^^xx` notation works as long as `inputenc` with the correct encoding is used:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\begin{document}
A word in Russian: ^^d0^^9f^^d1^^80^^d0^^b8^^d0^^b2^^d0^^b5^^d1^^82^^21
\end{document}
```

[image]

So, the question is: Is it really a bug in LuaTeX and XeTeX engines? Or should I report bugs to packages which are supposed to be used with these engines and use `^^xx^^xx` notation (like https://ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/gost?lang=en `ugost2008.bst` specifically)?

Comment: 'The rules are different' - as thee engines are UTF-8, they simply have a different approach. I'm not sure that would be an answer as such ...

Comment: the numbers don't mean bytes, but unicode code points with luatex and xetex, and e.g. 9F isn't a glyph in unicode, but a control char, see https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/009f/index.htm

Comment: Is there a *rule* for figuring out the 4-carat equivalent for 2-carat input, or vice versa?   For example, nothing jumps out at me why `^^d0^^9f` would be the equivalent of `^^^^041f`.  If a rule exists, I might be able to develop a converter of some sort.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Yes, that makes sense. So, macro packages shouldn't use `^^` if they are supposed to run both for LuaTeX/XeTeX and PdfTex.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes It's [UTF-8 encoding](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8): The 2-caret notation encodes the UTF-8 encoded bytes, the 4-caret notation encodes the Unicode codepoint directly.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger So I presume there is a mapping that needs to be done somewhere to resolve the two formats to point to the same glyph.  And my question is if the mapping is formulaic or merely tabular.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Right. It's formulaic and the formulas can be found at the link. For example `^^d0` in binary is `11010000`, so it starts with `110` indicating that it starts a sequence of two bytes. The remaining 5 bits are shifted left by 6 bits to `10000000000` or `0x400`. Then `0x80` is subtracted from the second byte (since all non-initial bytes start have `10` as their most significant bits) leading to 0x9f-0x80=0x1f which is added to the previous value, resulting in `0x41f` (aka. `U+41F` aka. `^^^^041f`).

Comment: @MarcelKrüger Excellent.  Thank you for the detailed and informative reply.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes and latex has code to calculate this. The error messages `! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character Δ (U+0394)` are a proof.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Great.  But, for whatever reason, xelatex and lualatex don't make use of those formulae in converting the two-carat sequences...presumably because the result is redundant to just using a 4-carat sequence.  Nonetheless, it would seem to me there is value in having a ready-made way to digest either sequence with the same result.

Comment: `^^xx` inserts characters, not bytes. Even in `pdftex` it inserts characters, which are post-processed to generate pseudo-Unicode characters, which in turn are converted to codepoints in a font.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes why should xelatex/lualatex convert this? 9F is a valid input, only not the one code targetting pdflatex expects. But that is not the problem of the engine but of the code.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I agree it is a problem of the code, not the engine.  But, as the OP notes, if one wishes to write code for multiple engines, either certain type of code has to be replaced when changing engines, or some kind of auto-conversion be offered.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes no you can simply writ ethe utf-8 character and it will work in xetex luatex and pdftex, input shown is valid but refers to two unicode code points not a single character.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I think you just answered my true question.  The magic babelfish tokens to use across all engines are the actual utf-8 characters. Duh.  I feel stupid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a bug, simply you are inputting the wrong characters.  The input

```
^^d0^^9f
```

is valid but is the two character sequence U+00D0 U+009F not the single character U+0422

There is no reason to use `^^` encode UTF-8 bytes, simply use `^^^^0422` or `\Uchar"0422` or the character `Т` directly. The last form, using Т has the advantage that it is also understood by pdflatex's inputenc decoder.